# error while inserting drop down list values in database

Tags: sql-server

I have some of the below values in a drop down list values:

```
 9:00 AM-10:00 AM
10:00 AM-11:00 AM etc.
```

I want to insert the above values in database in dotnet.
But while executing the program, it shows "Input string not in correct format".

My code is as below :

```
int d = Convert.ToInt32(drdTimeInterval.SelectedValue);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Slot values(@Slot_id,@Slot time)", con);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Slot_id", txtSlotId.Text);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Slot time",d);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Could anyone help me why I am getting the above error and also if there is any simpler way to do this?

Comment: `@slot time` is not a valid parameter. the space turns that into `parameter randomword`. try `@slot_time`

Comment: still not working giving the same error

Comment: then you'd have to explain your table structure (what are the field types, especially), and shoe actual values that you're inserting, not what you have in your form.